# code after servicehost.open method not executing

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding

i am learning wcf and working on a sample example. in this, i built a dll for wcf service and 2 windows applications for hosting the service and another client appn. in hosting appn, i cant get to execute the code after servicehost.open method. i am just curious to know whats going on. please help.

The code in the hosting appn is as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using WCFService;
namespace WCFServiceHost
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ServiceHost sh = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Uri tcpa = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8000/TcpBinding");

            sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceClass), tcpa);
            NetTcpBinding tcpb = new NetTcpBinding();
            ServiceMetadataBehavior mBehave = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(mBehave);
            sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange),
            MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(), "mex");
            sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IServiceClass), tcpb, tcpa);
            sh.Open();
**//This line is not executed
            label1.Text = "Service Running";
//This line is not executed**
        }
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            sh.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

one more help: how can we add service reference in visual studio 2005.

Comment: Why can't you execute that line? Do you get exception when opening service? What is it?

Comment: hi Mr Maciej i have copied the excepiton log. check the coments below.

Comment: Are you sure you dont already have something listening on port 8000?

Comment: Much thanks..now i changed port number to 8100,then it works. but when i try to add service reference,im getting this err Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8100/TcpBinding'.
Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:8100/TcpBinding. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.1921254. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8100.

Comment: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8100
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possibilities:

- Form1_Load is not being called
- sh.Open() or one of the previous lines is throwing an exception

Place a try catch around your code. In the catch block, set the text to the text of the exception.

**Edit**

This is a rights issue. When you do sh.Open() the program should start listening on a port. Listening on a port requires permission.

If you start your program with "Run as Administrator" it should work.

Comment: hi mr shiraz, this is the exception log. i am wiriting this in multiple comments boxes as the whole exceeds the limit of box.

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: A TCP error (10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions) occurred while listening on IP Endpoint=0.0.0.0:8000. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Comment: at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionListener.Listen()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionListener.Listen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnectionListener.Listen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ExclusiveTcpTransportManager.OnOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener channelListener)

Comment: the exception occurs at sh.open method. coopied the exception log above

Comment: i run the programwith admin privileges.(run as administrator) but no luck. when i changed the prot number as told by @BugFinder, it works.

Comment: Then your problem was that the firewall on your PC was blocking the port that you were using.

Comment: how can we determine whether the port used in service would be blocked by firewall, port number used in the service is already used by system(development server) where serive is developed. is it like we can only know when an exception occurs? how can we make firewall allow the connection in this context?